# Accessing object properties by variable

Tags: php

I've seen this asked before, but my particular case appears to be someone odd, and I'm unable to resolve it - any insight would be appreciated.

I'm trying to access an object property with a variable value, ie.

```
$foo = new Object();
$foo->first = 'bar';

$array = array(0 =>'first', 1 =>'second');

$var = 0;

return $foo->{$array[$var]};
```

This is throwing an error "Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$first".  Removing the braces  returns an identical result.

What don't I understand? (Actual code and error below - the error is as recorded in a Drupal Watchdog log.)

```
private function load_questionnaire_queue($type, $comparator_id, $comparing_id_array)
{
  $queue = array();
  $type_map = array(
    0 => "field_portfolio_district['und'][0]['nid']",
    1 => "field_time_period['und'][0]['tid']",
  );

  foreach ($this->questionnaires as $q)
  {

    // The commented code below works as expected
    // if ($q->field_portfolio_district['und'][0]['nid'] == $comparator_id &&
    //      in_array($q->field_time_period['und'][0]['tid'], $comparing_id_array))

    // This returns an identical error, with or without braces:
    if ($q->{$type_map[$type]} == $comparator_id && 
            in_array($q->{$type_map[!$type]}, $comparing_id_array))
    {
      $queue[] = node_view($q, $view_mode = 'full');
    }
  }

  $this->queue = $queue;
}
```

> Notice: Undefined property:
>   stdClass::$field_portfolio_district['und'][0]['nid'] in
>   ComparisonChart->load_questionnaire_queue()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works like a charm:

```
<?php
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->first = 'bar';

$array = array(0 =>'first', 1 =>'second');

$var = 0;

echo $foo->{$array[$var]};
?>
```

But I doubt this is gonna work:

```
<?php
$foo = new StdClass();
$foo->first = array('a' => array('b' => 'test'));

$array = array(0 =>'first["a"]["b"]', 1 =>'second');

$var = 0;

echo $foo->{$array[$var]};
?>
```

Comment: The solution here would be eval() but I would strongly advise you not to use eval or a method like this.

Comment: I was trying to be too fancy.  I'll just refactor.

Comment: Please do! Accessing methods via string variables makes debugging hell. F.I. you cannot use "Find usage" in Net beans when using variables to access functions. And believe me, this can be a pain in the ass!