# How to get access to class field which is variable

Tags: php, json

Firstly, look [my example json output](http://jsonfiddle.net/6z1rj).

I have next question. I have some fields in json code like 'counter_87' or 'coutner_88' in countersData part. It is a variable. I need to get access to this variable class field.

Ofc, I can write:

```
foreach($objCounter->countersData as $data)
{
    print $data->counter_87;
}
```

It is working fine. But...

I have counters ID and I need to get access to fields which are named depending on this ID's.

Full code, which will show what I want:

```
foreach($objCounter->countersData as $data)
{
    $row = "<td width=100px>$data->month $data->year</td>";
    foreach($objCounter->counters as $counter)
    {
        $counterId = $counter->id;
        $counterValue = "$data->counter_$counterId";
        $row .= "<td>$counterValue</td>";
    }
    $table .= "<tr>$row</tr>";
}
```

I need same:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$bar = 'foobar';
echo $$foo; // foobar will be printed
```

But with classes.

Thank you.

Comment: If you have properties like `counter_87` and `counter_88`, you probably should be using an array instead of separate properties.

Comment: why you decode to object ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing object properties by variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753583/accessing-object-properties-by-variable)

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean (about arrays)? Example please.

Comment: If you have variables or properties with numbered suffixes, it would be better to collect them into an array. So instead of `$data->counter_88` it would be `$data->counter[88]`. Then you can do `$data->counter[$counterId]`, or `foreach ($data->counter as $c)`, etc.

Comment: How json have to be rewrited then? I am not professional :D just newb :) It is interesting idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do the following if you don't want to or can't change change your JSON structure as already mentioned in the comments.

```
$field_name = 'counter_'.$id;
$field_value = $data->$field_name;
$row .= "<td>$field_value</td>";
// or $row .= '<td>'.$data->$field_name.'</td>';
```

About rewriting the JSON. Here's code that would convert your JSON to the slightly better structure.

```
$data = json_decode($data_json);
foreach($data->countersData as $counter_data) {
    $counters = array();
    foreach($counter_data as $key => $val) {
        if(substr($key, 0, 8) == 'counter_') {
            $counters[substr($key, 8)] = $val;
            unset($counter_data->$key);
        }
    }
    $counter_data->counters = $counters;
}
$data_json_new = json_encode($data);
```

Using an array instead of fields like 'counter_1', 'counter_2' means having structure like this this:

```
$countersData[0]->counters[90] = 1;
$countersData[0]->counters[89] = 1;
$countersData[0]->counters[88] = 1;
```

Instead of

```
$countersData[0]->counters_90 = 1;
$countersData[0]->counters_89 = 1;
$countersData[0]->counters_88 = 1;
```

This means having an associative array called counters instead of separate fields like 'counter_90' or something. It makes accessing the data programmatically alot easier.

Note that associative array is very similar to the stdClass. Basically a different datatype serving the same purpose. Using an array to represent your data just makes it easier to deal with integer keys. You can use json_decode($data_json, true) to get the data returned as an associative array.

Comment: Its done atm . This error appearing: `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string (44 line)`. 42-44 line: `$counterId = $counter->id; $field_name = 'counter_'.$counterId;$row .= "<td>$data->$field_name</td>";`

Comment: It's because you can't but $data->$field_name into double quoted string in php. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Working now. You answered the question :)

Comment: Hm. Maybe you can explain how to use array instead of object? With example :)

Comment: I added what I could.

Comment: I have access to json generator, so its better to restructure json at this step, not when you do it. Anyway thank you . You helped a lot. I understand it can work better, but I don't know how . ty. [all working fine now](http://i.gyazo.com/07e25bcaa958098ee9a907209075cb37.png)